# Ember.JS && Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

I know there is the ember-rails gem, however this generates javascript instead of Coffeescript.  I was curious if there was a gem that included the generators for coffeescript, or if there was a way to get ember-rails to do this.  Being that coffeescript is default in Rails 3, I figured this would also be the default.  Obviously I can hand create all the files, I just was curious so that others on the team did not have to create these files.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that it's on its way: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/pull/93
Until its merged into the ember-rails gem you could just add the modified version to your 
Gemfile:
`gem 'ember-rails', github: 'adrulz/ember-rails'`

Haven't tried it but it looks OK.